# Suggestion for a specific view android

Tags: android, layout, view

I would like to create a new application of weather,
i did some research to find inspiration for the design,
i found this
[image]

I wonder how can I do that ! mabye with listview

if you have any suggestion please help

thanx in your advance

Comment: Do you have a specific, code related question? What have you tried already?

Comment: I have a listview ( with weekdays, temperature, icon) and now i try to change height of row to show more information,
I think that I must use other view than listview no ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of possibilities.

You could use :

Native (API android) :

https://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html

Canvas in the Android API

AndEngine (GLES 2)

---

Check out ressources :

Android Arsenal (which android specific public depository)

https://android-arsenal.com/

Sincerly yours.

Comment: I can't use material design because my application support the previous  version.
Thanx for the last link I like it.